# Copy rows to another sheet while maintaining original referencing

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with rows of data. There is a second sheet which uses a reference formula to pull from this data. I am making a third sheet where I may need to copy rows from the second sheet varying numbers of times. However, I need it to pull from the original cells (i.e. use absolute referencing, but while copy-pasting data instead of putting a dollar sign on everything). Currently it just maps to the corresponding row in the first sheet which I don't want.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out... ctrl+shift+v to just copy the values